# How to use the setarch uname command in a shell script

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, ksh

I am trying to create a korn shell script in RHEL7 to silently install an agent at my job. However the agent requires an old version of the agent be installed before being upgraded to the new version of the agent. The upgraded version of the agent will work with RHEL 7s new 3.x linux core but the base version of the agent will not. The company instructed us to use the command `setarch $(uname -m) --uname-2.6`, install the base agent, then exit out of the setarch shell and install the upgrade. My problem is up until now I had all of this silently scripted but the setarch command drops the script in to a shell and stops running script commands. Is there any way to issue the setarch command and continue to run the script or execute a second script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run your whole install script under setarch

```
$ setarch $(uname -m) --uname-2.6 /path/to/install/script.sh
```

Everything called in that script onwards will think you're running a 2.6 kernel.

Comment: I need to run two install scripts however. The first one needs to be run in that setarch shell, the second one needs to be run in the normal shell.

Comment: `setarch .... script1 ; script2`

Comment: Yeah, no sooner than I said it then I realized that I didn't need to do the whole script so much as just the one install script. I should take 10 seconds to think about the answer before replying. Thank you Stephen.